# How to get the comment from a .resx file entry

Tags: c#, resx

Strings in resource files have a name, a value and a comment
The `ResXResourceReader` class gives me access to the name and the value.
Is there a way to read the comment?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should be able to get `Comment` via `ResXDataNode` class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxdatanode.aspx

You will need to set `UseResXDataNodes` flag on the reader: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcereader.useresxdatanodes.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Necromancing. 
If the link goes dark - with `UseResXDataNodes = true`:

```
public static string ReadRessourceFile()
{
    string[] languages = new string[] { "de", "fr", "it", "en" };
    string pathPattern = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    pathPattern = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathPattern, "..", "..", "..", "libQrCodeGenerator", "Resources", "QRBillText-{0}.resx");
    pathPattern = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(pathPattern);

    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>> dict = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>>(System.StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

    foreach (string lang in languages)
    {
        dict[lang] = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>(System.StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        string file = string.Format(pathPattern, lang);
        System.Resources.ResXResourceReader rr = new System.Resources.ResXResourceReader(file);
        rr.UseResXDataNodes = true;

        // '# Iterate through the resources and display the contents to the console. 
        foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry d in rr)
        {
            System.Resources.ResXDataNode node = (System.Resources.ResXDataNode)d.Value;
            string value = (string) node.GetValue((System.ComponentModel.Design.ITypeResolutionService)null);
            string comment = node.Comment;

            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comment))
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(comment);
            }

            // dict[lang][d.Key.ToString()] = d.Value.ToString(); // when not using UseResXDataNodes = true
            dict[lang][d.Key.ToString()] = value;
        }

        // '#Close the reader. 
        rr.Close();
    }

    string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    return json;
}
```