# Get the comments for a control from .resx file

Tags: c#, winforms, comments, controls, resx

My program is a translator that load a exe and the resx files that comes with it, edit them, save them and then put them in an assembly (with AS.exe). I can already change the text from controls, but I would like to change the comments associated with it.

I know resource file (.resx) can contain comments ... [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854404/how-to-get-the-comment-from-a-resx-file-entry)

[image]

My problem is that I have the form made from the resource file and when I try to access a control properties, I can only get the name and the text. I want to be able to get and set comment to a control (example: a button name : btnOk, text : Ok, comment : Ok button).

Once the control has the comment, I will save the resource file and I would like the comment to still be there and accessible next time I open the resx.

I put the data in a datagridview this way :

```
dgv.Rows.Add(new string[] { ctrl.Name, ctrl.Text, "Here should be the comments" });
```

Comment: So you want to edit the resx at run time?

Comment: @jrummell I have edit my post. Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: The forms designer just doesn't support comments.  You can certainly put the `<comment>` element inside the `<data>` element in the .resx file by hand but as soon as you edit you'll lose them again.