# How to get resource file comment from ResourceSet?

Tags: c#, resource-files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the comment from a .resx file entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854404/how-to-get-the-comment-from-a-resx-file-entry)

I loop through resource file using:

```
_cityResources = Cities.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(
                        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, 
                        true, 
                        true);

foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in CityResources)
{
    result.Add(new CityBounds()
    {
         Name = entry.Key as string,
         BoundingBox = (entry.Value as string).ToBoundingBox()
    });
}
```

and using key, value pair for my stuff.
And now I have a question:

How to get content from resource file, comment column in this loop?