# Is it possible to get a resource's comment using ResourceManager?

Tags: c#, resx, resourcemanager

I realize that this is essentially [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902179/how-to-get-resource-file-comment-from-resourceset), but it's accepted answer just points to a link that doesn't seem to do what the asker requested (it doesn't start from ResourceManager/ResourceSet).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

To get the resource content use:

```
            ResourceReader rr = new ResourceReader(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("resourceName"););

            IDictionaryEnumerator e = rr.GetEnumerator();
            string resourceType;

            byte[] resourceData;
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                string keyName = (string)e.Key;

                rr.GetResourceData(keyName, out resourceType, out resourceData);
            }
```

Comment: When I run this, this only gives me ResourceTypeCode.String and the actual resource value. I don't get the resource comment. How do you get the comment?

Answer (score -1):

The only thing I could currently think of, is if your read the .resx file with an xml reader.

Comment: Is there a reliable way that you can find that file at runtime?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? You could just iterate through all directories or something like that.

Comment: But when my DLL is deployed, I won't have my original directory structure, right?

Answer (score -1):

From this article :
[GetManifestResourceStream returns NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637830/getmanifestresourcestream-returns-null)

```
        string[] array = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
        string[] array2 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

Will help you to get resource name.

Comment: This returns the list of resource file names in the assembly, not the comments associated with resource keys in .resx files