# Is it possible to read 'Comment' from global resource file programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I could read the key and the value from the global resource file (Language) :

```
using (var reader = new ResXResourceReader(Server.MapPath(@"\App_GlobalResources\language" + language + ".resx")))
{
    resx = reader.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToList();
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resx)
    {
        if (entry.Key != null && entry.Value != null)
        {
            var key = entry.Key;
            var value = entry.Value;
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
}
```

Is it possible to read the third column (Comments) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the comment from a .resx file entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854404/how-to-get-the-comment-from-a-resx-file-entry)